# How to use CryptoJS with Angular

Tags: angularjs, cryptojs

All is in the title. I want to use the CrytoJS lib in an AngularJS application and I can't get rid of this.

I install crytoJS with bower:

```
bower install cryptojslib
```

Then I load the lib I need :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/system/lib/cryptojslib/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/system/lib/cryptojslib/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
```

And I try to use the CryptoJS like that :

```
var pwd = CryptoJS.MD5(params.email+'|'+params.password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

When I run this code, I've got the following error :

```
'CryptoJS is not defined'
```

I've read that it should be possible to wrap the CryptoJS into a module but I don't know how to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JM.

Comment: Are you including the libaries in your HTML before your Angular code, or after?

Comment: Is the order important ? I try different order with the plunker of Mike below and it change nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't be any problems with AngularJS and CryptoJS. I setup a quick Plunker that has a hash created in a controller. No errors...

http://plnkr.co/edit/kzrr3EdHNXELVof6DVSp?p=preview

In the controller:

```
$scope.hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
```

In the HTML:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
```

Is this different than what you are trying?

Comment: Thank's for your Plunker. I don't find any difference with my code. So I will change my glasses and verify all the chain.

Comment: OK I've got it... It's just a JSLint message but my code works when correctly called. Do you know if it possible to wrap it in a Module (to avoid the JSLint error message) ?

Comment: Would be nice if answer would stay up to date. Check the updated working example http://plnkr.co/edit/QoGj4xzqBtTKOdb1zYCy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

include the jsfile from rollups folder.

Even I was also getting the same error 'CryptoJS is not defined'. After this change, CryptoJS object was available

```
var hashObj = CryptoJS.SHA512(myString); 
var hashString = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.HEX);
```